# Apache Document Root using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory structure

```
mymvc
    |--App
    |--Core
    |--logs
    |--public
             |--index.php
    |--vendor
    |--.htaccess
```

what i want is that if someone hit my url `www.example.com/mymvc/` then all the request must go through `public->index.php`  using `.htaccess` file. i do not have access to httpd.conf file.

```
|--public
        |--index.php
```

I want my `public` folder to be accessible only as a document root and request pass through **index.php** file inside `public` folder. No one can access directly `App` , `Core` , `logs` etc. directories. Means i want my public folder to be `DOCUMENT ROOT`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to create an `.htaccess` file in the root of the project.

**mymvc/.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

Then, in the `.htaccess` file in the `public` directory (which would be **mymvc/public/.htaccess**), you need to add a `RewriteBase` directive to the existing code, so it looks like this:

**mymvc/public/.htaccess**

```
# Remove the question mark from the request but maintain the query string
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mymvc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Could you explain the details of why are needed two files?